# Python SystemHotkey registering from list causes all hotkeys bound to last action in list

Tags: python

I'm currently writing code which deals with hotkey implementation. When using the system_hotkey module I get weird behavior from reading the configuration file with hotkeys and registering them. Specifically, I've narrowed down the problem to the point where hotkeys are being registered from a list. The following code shows the isolated problem:

```
from system_hotkey import SystemHotkey

def test(num):
    print(num)

def listHKReg():
    hotkeys = [[["control", "1"], "test1"],[["control", "2"], "test2"]]
    for h in hotkeys:
        hk = SystemHotkey()
        hk.register(h[0], callback = lambda x:test(h[1]))
    while(True):
        pass

def hardCodeHKReg():
    hk = SystemHotkey()
    hk.register(["control", "1"], callback = lambda x:test("test1"))
    hk.register(["control", "2"], callback = lambda x:test("test2"))
    while(True):
        pass
```

When registering hotkeys with `hardCodeHKReg()` there's no issues with proper hotkey mapping. But when registering hotkeys with `listHKReg()` all hotkeys from the list exhibit the same behavior as the last registered hotkey's action from the list (i.e. ctrl+1 will print "test2").